# ASP.NET MVC 3 NOT showing appropriate view, action called using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a small problem.

My action is :

```
 public ViewResult SearchForRooms(int HotelDDL) 
    {

        List<Room> roomsInHotel = bl.ReturnRoomsPerHotel(HotelDDL);

        return View(roomsInHotel);
    }
```

Here is the jquery that is calling the action:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#HotelDDL").change(function () {

            var text = $("#HotelDDL option:selected").text();
            var value = $("#HotelDDL option:selected").val();
            alert("Selected text=" + text + " Selected value= " + value);

            $.post("/Home/SearchForRooms",
            {
                HotelDDL: $("#HotelDDL option:selected").val() 
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

And finally, here is the View that should be called:

```
@model IEnumerable<RoomReservation.Entities.Entities.Room>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Search";
}

<h2>Result</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            City
        </th>
        <th>
            Hotel
        </th>
        <th>
            Room label
        </th>
        <th>
            Number of beds
        </th>
        <th>
            Price per night
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem=>item.Hotel.City.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Hotel.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NumberOfBeds)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PricePerNight)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Everthing is working ok (databse return all rooms correctly) except final view rendering.
I have tried Phil's tool but it doesn't give me any suspicious hints:

```
RouteDebug.RouteDebugger.RewriteRoutesForTesting(RouteTable.Routes);
```

So, why is it not showing after jscript send it's post method to `SearchForRooms()`?
Thank you

P.S. If you need any other piece of code please just say so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that doing an ajax post will not refresh or redirect the page like a classic post would.

The view is not showing because there is no where to place it. You post successfully, and return a view successfully but then do nothing with it. If you want to show the returned view, then you have to append it to the dom somehow. Here is a common method:

```
<div id="successDiv"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#HotelDDL").change(function () {

        var text = $("#HotelDDL option:selected").text();
        var value = $("#HotelDDL option:selected").val();
        alert("Selected text=" + text + " Selected value= " + value);

        $.post("/Home/SearchForRooms",
         {
            HotelDDL: $("#HotelDDL option:selected").val() 
         }, function(result){//add callback for success - result is the returned view
            $("#successDiv").html(result);//place the view inside of the div
        });
    });
 });
</script>
```

---

**Comment Response**

@TunAntun - You should use a classic post if you want the view to have its own page. There is no way to accomplish this from ajax. You could do this with javascript though

```
 $.post("/Home/SearchForRooms",
         {
            HotelDDL: $("#HotelDDL option:selected").val() 
         }, function(result){//add callback for success - result is the returned view
            $("#successDiv").html(result);//place the view inside of the div
        });
```

would become

```
        var postForm = document.createElement("form");
        postForm.setAttribute("method","post");
        postForm.setAttribute("action","/Home/SearchForRooms");
        var postVal = document.createElement("input");
        postVal.setAttribute("type","hidden");
        postVal.setAttribute("name","HotelDDL");
        postVal.setAttribute("value",$("#HotelDDL option:selected").val() );
        postForm.appendChild(postVal);
        document.body.appendChild(postForm);
        $(postForm).submit();
```

This will dynamically issue the post you wanted. Then in your controller it will properly redirect or return a view. It is highly suggested that when returning a view from a `[HttpPost]` that you use `RedirectToAction` and then return the view from a `[HttpGet]` method in order to prevent refresh from reposting old data.

Comment: If I do place view inside <div id = "successDiv"><div/> then my Model is not working anymore and have to change it. But let's say I modified it. What about when I want View to have it's own page? Thanks

Comment: ok, can I just ask one more thing. I have two drop downs and one ok button. First DDL is filled normally from base and ajax is used to fill another DDL (the one in this question). Is there a better way to do this (2 dropdowns). I guess I made this much more complicated then needed.

Comment: @TunAntun - Pretty common to load data for a dropdown with ajax based on the value of the first one. Another approach would be to eager load all of the data in the second list and then filter it based on the selection from the first one.